# how to return multiple values from NPAPI plugin method to javascript

Tags: javascript, plugins, npapi

To my knowledge, the NPAPI plugin methods return only the NPVariant *result.
But i need a multiple strings and integers that are passed to the plugin method as parameters, modified inside the plugin method and then their modified value is used in the javascript that is calling this plugin method.
Can i get some help regarding this matter?
Is it the case that only the value that is returned by the method can be used in javascript or we just need the variable type to be NPVariant for it to be usable in the javascript without the plugin method returning it.

Answer (score 0):

in js, you return multiple value by array or object (afaik, they are pretty much the same.) and I guess you just need the same technique for npapi plugin, i.e. create a object, do what ever you want (add what ever field you need in it), and return it.

I think you can also use the similar way to simulate the fallowing js code

```
function (obj) {
    obj.n = 2;
    obj.strs[0] = '';
    obj.strs[1] = 'a';
}
```

(sure you need to check the type of obj etc.)

(basically my point is you just need to simulate what you can do in js~~)

(haven't try myself, tell me if I am wrong)